# Bootstrap not working on VS 2013 after update to version 3.3.1

Tags: visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap-3

On VS 2013 (update 3) I create the standard MVC5 web app and when I resize the browser to a smaller size, the Bootstrap works perfectly as it always do. But after I updated the package from version 3.0.0 to 3.3.1 (the latest), using Project->Manage NuGet Packages, the Bootstrap doesn't work anymore. When resizing the browser (to a smaller size), the fonts and the controls don't scale down anymore as they did before. Why is this happening?

UPDATED ON 05 / 14 /2015 !!!!!!!!!!!

Now using Bootstrap version 3.3.4

The problem was only with IE and after I added the line below, it worked!

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10; IE=9; IE=8; IE=7; IE=EDGE" />
```

But now, although the columns do resize accordingly, the font-size does not. Is this the new behavior for modern browsers or is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Is there any Microsoft JS/CSS NuGet packages that also need updating? I would suspect it would have updated them as dependencies though.

Comment: I did an "Update All" for all installed packages but it didn't solve it.

Comment: Latest upstream Bootstrap is v3.2.2...

Comment: Bootstrap version is now v3.3.2 ...