# What files need to be added in BundleConfig.cs after updating to Bootstrap version 3.3.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

In previous versions of Bootstrap, the BundleConfig in MVC 5 was:

```
   bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js"));
```

And the ..\Content folder had the file: bootstrap.css

Now, after updating to Bootstrap version 3.3.4 I see the adtl files in the ..\Content folder:

bootstrap-theme.css and bootstrap-theme.css.map

The question is: Should these two files be added to the BundleConfig as follow?

```
   bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
              "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css",
              "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css.map",
              "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bootstrap.theme.css` [is optional](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23522301/314291) and is useful only if you want to change the default theme / roll a theme.

The `.map.css` file is only useful if you've also used the minified (`.min.css`) version of a css file - `.map` files are provided for [debugging minified files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21504707/314291).

So, unless you intend debugging and/or custom styling bootstrap, I would bundle just the `~/Content/bootstrap.min.css` in the `StyleBundle` config and leave out the themes altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Would it be possible for you to also take a look at this question in the link below?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228501/bootstrap-not-working-on-vs-2013-after-update-to-version-3-3-1